# Using STL functions with a struct?

Tags: c++, stl

I've recently read up on STL functions in C++. I understand the basic uses of the functions, but I am struggling getting them to use member variables of a struct.

I have this struct:

```cpp
struct Apples
{
   double weight; // oz
   string color;  // red or green
   void print() const { cout << color << ", " <<  weight << endl; }
};
```

Basically, I insert `Apples` into a `vector` storing random weights and random color. Now, I want to use a `count_if` function to determine how many apples are greater than a given weight. I want to convert a function like this:

```cpp
int cnt = 0;
for(auto it = crate.cbegin(); it != crate.cend(); ++it) 
    if(it->weight > toFind) 
        cnt++;
```

to a `count_if()` version (this does not work):

```cpp
int cnt = count_if(crate.begin(), crate,end(), isGreater())
```

With `isGreater()` being like this:

```cpp
void isGreater()
{
   if(it->weight > toFind) 
      return it->weight > toFind;
}
```

What I don't understand about STL functions and a `struct` is how to use the member variables inside of the struct with the STL functions. I'm not sure what to pass inside of the STL function, either. Would it be better to use a lambda function in this case? If so, why?

Here is all the current code, if it doesn't make sense:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

struct Apples
{
   double weight; // oz
   string color;  // red or green
   void print() const { cout << color << ", " <<  weight << endl; }
};

void isGreater()
{
   if(it->weight > toFind) 
      return it->weight > toFind;
}

int main()
{
   srand(time(nullptr));
   const double minWeight = 8.;
   const double maxWeight = 3.;

   cout << "Input crate size: ";
   int size;
   cin >> size;

   vector <Apples> crate(size);
   for(auto it = crate.begin(); it != crate.end(); ++it)
   {
      it->weight = minWeight + static_cast<double>(rand())/RAND_MAX*(maxWeight - minWeight);
      it->color = rand() % 2 == 1 ? "green" : "red";
   }

   cout << "Enter weight to find: ";
   double toFind;
   cin >> toFind;

  //this is what I want to convert to count if
   int cnt = 0;
   for(auto it = crate.cbegin(); it != crate.cend(); ++it) 
      if(it->weight > toFind) 
         cnt++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::count_if` takes unary predicate as the third argument. In this case unary predicate is a function taking one object and returning `true` if object matches find criterion or `false` if not.

Since your criterion depends on `toFind`, it seems more laconic to use lambda capturing `toFind`:

```cpp
int cnt = count_if(crate.begin(), crate.end(), [toFind](const Apple& apple) {
  return it->weight > toFind;
});
```

If you want a standalone function, you can use:

```cpp
bool isGreater(double toFind, const Apple& apple) {
   return it->weight > toFind;
}

...

int cnt = count_if(crate.begin(), crate.end(),
        std::bind(&isGreater, toFind, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Note, that you don't need to call function, you need to pass it:

```
int cnt = count_if(crate.begin(), crate,end(), isGreater())
//                                                      ^^ remove parentheses
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not storing the apples in the vector.
you have to initialize inside a loop each apple and then store them in the vector.
crate.push_back(newApple).
so run a loop from 0 to size.
inside that loop initialize new apples and give them weights and colors
then push_back in vector:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size ++i)
 { 
   apples newApple;
   newApple.weight = ...;
   newApple.color = ...;
   crate.push_back(newApple);
 }
```

Comment: I am storing in the first part of int main().

Answer (score 0):

This is usually accomplished by creating a "functor" class, a class whose objects can be called like a function. Each instance call hold the reference weight:

```
struct IsGreater {
    double w;
    IsGreater(double weight) : w{weight} {}
    bool operator()(const Apples& A) const {
         return A.weight > w;
    }
};
```

Then we just need to create an instance of the class holding the reference weight and pass it to `count_if`:

```
const int count = std::count_if(crate.begin(), crate.end(), IsGreater(toFind));
```

You can avoid creating an explicit class using a lambda:

```
const int count = std::count_if(crate.begin(), crate.end(),
                               [=](const Apples& A) -> bool {
                                    return A.weight > toFind;
                               });
```

Here the reference value `toFind` is captured by value.